# Changing inline in flowdocument

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox, flowdocument

I have a flowdocument like this:

```
var mcFlowDoc = new FlowDocument();
var para = new Paragraph();
para.Inlines.Add(new Run("This is the first line."));
para.Inlines.Add(new Run("This is the second line."));
para.Inlines.Add(new Run("This is the third line."));
mcFlowDoc.Blocks.Add(para);
richTextBox.Document = mcFlowDoc;
```

I need to change the background of one of the lines by clicking on any part of that text.

First of all I am trying to change the background of a given inline (regardless of mouse click), but I am unable to do it.

Any help would be appreciated.

**Edit:**
I could change the background color of a run, but then I had to add all runs again and redraw.
I need it to work faster, so I'm just trying to change a run without adding all again.

Comment: what have you tried yet? Can't you add "Background" property to Run() element?

Comment: Please check the edit. Yes, I can. But I need it to run faster.

Comment: Try calling InvalidateVisual on Run() element after changing Background. Won't that update it, without removing?

Comment: Sorry, I am a newbie when it comes to wpf. Would you show me the code. Say I want to highlight "This is the second line.", what should I do. And the second question, how do I detect mouse click?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a `Style` for `Run` to subscribe e.g. `MouseLeftButtonDown`

```
<RichTextBox.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Run">
        <EventSetter Event="MouseLeftButtonDown" Handler="Run_Click" />
    </Style>
</RichTextBox.Resources>
```

and handle the event like this

```
void Run_Click(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    Run run = sender as Run;
    run.Background = Brushes.Red;
}
```

Comment: Would you please explain where to insert the first piece of code?

Comment: If you haven't declared your RichTextBox in XAML then add this Style in Window.Resources in MainWindow.xaml. But I strongly recommend using XAML declarations.

Comment: Would you please tell me how to get the index of the clicked run? Thanks!

Comment: Again this is the wrong approach. Use MVVM otherwise this will be a mess. At the moment `var paragraph = run.Parent as Paragraph; var index = paragraph.Inlines.ToList().IndexOf(run);` will give you the zero based index but after the next change in FlowDocument structure this can be broken.

Comment: OK, thank you very much. Another point: I tried your code for "TextBlock" instead of "Run" but it didn't work. Can this be fixed? Thanks

Comment: This is exactly what i meant. Yes, this can be fixed over and over.

Comment: Please take a look at this, it's the same but for textblock: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17908449/clicking-on-a-textblock-in-wpf-richtextbox