# Clicking on a TextBlock in WPF richtextbox

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox, textblock

I have a flowdocument like this:

```
var mcFlowDoc = new FlowDocument();
var para = new Paragraph();
para.Inlines.Add(textBlock1);
para.Inlines.Add(textBlock2);
para.Inlines.Add(textBlock3);
mcFlowDoc.Blocks.Add(para);
richTextBox1.Document = mcFlowDoc;
```

and I need an event to trigger on mouse click on a textblock:

```
    <RichTextBox Margin="10,10,230,12" Name="richTextBox1" FontFamily="Simplified Arabic" FontSize="16" IsReadOnly="True" IsReadOnlyCaretVisible="False" ForceCursor="False" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <RichTextBox.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="Run">
                <EventSetter Event="MouseLeftButtonDown" Handler="Run_Click" />
            </Style>
            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                <EventSetter Event="MouseLeftButtonDown" Handler="TextBlock_Click" />
            </Style>
        </RichTextBox.Resources>
    </RichTextBox>

void TextBlock_Click(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            TextBlock tb = sender as TextBlock;
        }
```

The event handler for Run is called and works properly ([Changing inline in flowdocument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17906948/changing-inline-in-flowdocument)) , but that for TextBlock isn't.

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: You assign FlowDocument to richTextBox. Are you sure richTextBox1 has FlowDocument with TextBlocks too?

Comment: Yes, this is what I use: textBlock1 = new TextBlock(run1));

Comment: I meant you have probably two RichTextBoxes. One named richTextBox with FlowDocument and one declared in XAML named richTextBox1 without content but with event handling.

Comment: Sorry, both are richTextBox1. I just edited the question.

Answer (score 5):

Quote from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox.aspx):

> Important
>
> RichTextBox has built-in handling for the bubbling MouseUp and MouseDown events. Consequently, custom event handlers that listen for MouseUp or MouseDown events from a RichTextBox will never be called. If you need to respond to these events, listen for the tunneling PreviewMouseUp and PreviewMouseDown events instead, or register the handlers with the HandledEventsToo argument (this latter option is only available through code). Do not mark the event handled unless you deliberately want to disable RichTextBox native handling of these events, and be aware that this has notable effects on the control's UI.

So you need to look for alternatives. I can suggest a few.

First, you can set an event handler `PreviewMouseDown` for all `RichTextBox`:

```
<RichTextBox PreviewMouseDown="TextBlock_Click" ... />
```

Second, use the `BlockUIContainer` and put the text in the content button. For example:

```
<Paragraph FontSize="18">Flow Example</Paragraph>

<BlockUIContainer>
  <Button x:Name="MyButton" ClickMode="Release" Click="Button_Click">
    <TextBlock Margin="4" TextWrapping="Wrap">
      Some text
    </TextBlock>
  </Button>
</BlockUIContainer>
```

Third, you can set the event handler for the `Paragraph` like that:

```
var para = new Paragraph();
para.Inlines.Add(textBlock1);

para.MouseLeftButtonDown += new MouseButtonEventHandler(TextBlock_Click);
```

**`Edit`**

Quote from Adam Nathan's book `WPF 4 Unleashed`:

> Whereas TextBox exposes simple integer properties such as CaretIndex, SelectionStart, and SelectionEnd, RichTextBox exposes a CaretPosition property of type TextPointer and a Selection property of type TextSelection. In addition, RichTextBox’s content is stored in a Document property of type FlowDocument rather than the simple string Text property. The content can even contain embedded UIElements, and they can be interactive and raise events if RichTextBox’s IsDocumentEnabled property is set to true.

Events began to work, it is necessary to add `BlockUIContainer` with [`IsDocumentEnabled`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox.isdocumentenabled.aspx) property is set to *`true`* (in `RichTextBox`), otherwise, the event will not working altogether.

In general, I do not understand why you need it `TextBlock` inside `RichTextBox`. Use it the standard features, they pretty much cover, those `Run`, `Paragraph`, etc. If they do not match, then there is no reason to use `RichTextBox`.

See the nice tutorial about `RichTextBox` [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee681613%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, but I forgot to mention that the similar code for the Run works properly (I just edited the question). Why wouldn't TextBlock works as well?

Comment: @Jerry: I think the answer is in the quote: `custom event handlers that listen for MouseUp or MouseDown events from a RichTextBox`. Apparently, this applies to the content in `RichTextBox`. I've tried various mouse events for `TextBlock`, but it did not work.

Comment: Yes, but it worked for runs in the richtextbox too. Did you tried that? Are they treated differently?

Comment: Sorry, after looking more into it, this isn't exactly what I need. The textblock I have needs to be set in code, not xaml, and is part of paragraph, so I don't want to put each of them in a paragraph.

Comment: Would you please give me details? I am a newbied with wpf.

Comment: @Jerry: Okay, I'll look at this question about `TextBlock`, let you know if I would find some info.

Comment: Thanks. I originally used a textblock because I had a Run and I wanted to raise it above line level, and I could only find the baselineoffset property with textblock.

Comment: @Jerry: I think you should not use this `TextBlock`. Try to solve the problem of abilities `RichTextBox`. Anyway, an event in `TextBlock` that to work, you know what to do.